# I want to loop through a file assigning a variable to specific tokens, then use the variables in a command line

Tags: for-loop, batch-file, cmd

I am a newbi and apologize if I am not asking the question correctly, but I want to loop through a list, assigning a variable to specific tokens in that list, then pass the variables to a command (using both variables for each variable 1???  Not sure if I am asking the question properly.

The WK1List1 has something like this:

```
servername ipaddress
anotherservername anotheripaddress
```

-- batch segment is --

```
::format date in yyyy-mm-dd to apply to a directory, use is
For /f "tokens=2-4 delims=/ " %%a in ('date /t') do (set today=%%c-%%a-%%b)

set homedir=E:\backups
set backuplog=E:\backups\LOGS\wk1-errors.log
set WK1List1=E:\backups\Lists\Week1_VMList_1.txt


SETLOCAL EnableDelayedExpansion
SET count=1
FOR /F "tokens=1 delims= usebackq" %%a IN ("%WK1List1%") DO (
SET var!count!=%%a
SET /a count=!count!+1

SET count=1
FOR /F "tokens=2 delims= usebackq" %%b IN ("%WK1List1%") DO (
SET var!count!=%%b
SET /a count=!count!+1
call :runbkup
)

:runbkup
echo "%%a backup started on %DATE% at %TIME%" >%backuplog% 2<&1
if exist %homedir%\%%a Rename %homedir%\%%a%_temp
start "%%a" cmd /c vcbmounter.exe -h vc2.domain.local -u domain\uid -p pwd -m `nbd -a ipaddr:%%b -r %homedir%\%%a -t fullvm -M 1
if exist "%homedir%\%%a" RD "%homedir%\%%a%_temp" /Q /S
echo "%%a backup completed on %DATE% at %TIME%" >>%backuplog% 2<&1
if exist "%homedir%\%%a_temp" echo "%%a was not successful on %DATE%-pls investigate" >>%backuplog% 2<&1

ENDLOCAL
```

Comment: Show part of your list and where you need to separate the tokens, please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sadly, you seem to have censored your batch way too hard. As it stands, little makes much sense, but here goes...

First, you carefully set up  `today` - but don't use it.

Then you appear to want to set up `var1`..`varn` as the servernames. Well, OK - but after updating the count, you need  to end the `DO` block - so you've omitted the closing parenthesis.

Then - if you put in the omitted parenthesis, you are repeating the action, and setting the **VERY SAME** array, `var1`..`varn` to the ipaddresses.

THEN you aren't using the `var` array anyway! It doesn't appear in the rest of the batch.

Having set `var1` to the ipaddress of line 1, you then `CALL` the backup routine - where `%%a` and `%%b` are out-of-context and hence would likely be replacd by the LITERAL string `%a` and `%b`...

Now leaving `:runbkup` well alone for the moment, when the `FOR...%%b` loop finishes, batch won't terminate like Delphi or Pascal - it'll just charge on through the label...

Turning to `:runbkup` -

No point to the `2<&1` in an echo statement, and the redirector seems in the wrong direction anyway.

the `>%backlog%` will **RESTART** the logfile - delete the original and send the `ECHO`ed text to a new one.

the `rename` command has no destination name.

So - how do we deal with this trainwreck?

Well - 'tis batch, so it's easy.

```
@echo off
::format date in yyyy-mm-dd to apply to a directory, use is
For /f "tokens=2-4 delims=/ " %%a in ('date /t') do (set today=%%c-%%a-%%b)
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set homedir=E:\backups
set backuplog=E:\backups\LOGS\wk1-errors.log
set WK1List1=E:\backups\Lists\Week1_VMList_1.txt

SET count=1
FOR /F "usebackq tokens=1,2 delims= " %%a IN ("%WK1List1%") DO (
SET var!count!=%%a
SET anothervar!count!=%%b
SET /a count=!count!+1
call :runbkup %%a %%b
)

GOTO :EOF

:runbkup
echo "%1 backup started on %DATE% at %TIME%" >>%backuplog%
if exist %homedir%\%1 Rename %homedir%\%1 %1_temp
start "%1" cmd /c vcbmounter.exe -h vc2.domain.local -u domain\uid -p pwd -m `nbd -a ipaddr:%2 -r %homedir%\%1 -t fullvm -M 1
if exist "%homedir%\%1" RD "%homedir%\%1_temp" /Q /S
echo "%1 backup completed on %DATE% at %TIME%" >>%backuplog%
if exist "%homedir%\%1_temp" echo "%1 was not successful on %DATE%-pls investigate" >>%backuplog%
GOTO :eof
```

[I haven't tried this - but it should work]

This version uses `tokens=1,2` to select the first and second tokens on the line read from the file. I have a personal preference  for placing the `usebackq` first so that it doesn't give `delims` a sequence of characters to use as delimiters in the case of a typo. The default delimiters are space, tab, comma, semicolon - so the `delims` clause is superfluous, but harmless.

the `var` and `anothervar` arrays are set to the servernames and ipaddresses - even if you don't use them.

`:runbkup` is called with two parameters - so these appear as `%1` and `%2` as far as the subroutine is concerned, so the routine's `%%a` gets replaced by `%1` and `%%b` by `%2`

Beyond that, as you had it - with the omission of the `2<&1`, appending (`>>`) to the log and giving the `rename` the destination name you evidently intended.

I'd draw your attention to the `VCBMOUNTER` line - I've no experience with that application, but the sequence "-m `nbd" in the original puzzles me. Very unusual.

HTH

Comment: Thank you so much, I will give this a try..I know it is a train wreck as it was put together, obviously, with bits and pieces of knowledge. I was just not understanding how I could pass the variables setup in the text to the command line. I will let you know how it goes.  Also the vcbmounter is a vcb command for  Consolidated backups of vms.